# SilverStripe Swipestripe - How to add input field for Product variation?

Tags: product, silverstripe, swipestripe

I have product like Greeting Cards. In which there is an option to add user defined printed message in card with extra charges. How to modify the ProductForm without changing original file to add TextareaField on product page? In that field user can add message and then will proceed to "Add to cart".

**Edit:** I'm using Swipestripe Ecommerce module. But don't know the inner functionality perfectly as I'm new to it. It call ProductForm.php file by `$ProductForm` on Product.ss template. This form has a "select list box" of Variation. "Quantity" input field and "Add To Cart" button.  I need to add "Message" Textarea input field after "select list box".

Comment: It's hard to tell how your setup may look :) More details about data model or used modules could help to provide you the needed information. In general I think DataExtension does what your after:
http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/

Comment: @munomono I've edited question. I tried to add screenshot, but as my rep score is less than 10 I can't post an image. Hope this edit can clear about what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @wmk I need help again. Please check this question.